# Getting core dumps when free() is used

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, coredump

I'm doing a school assignment and the driver was given to me along with the header file.  My job is to complete the functions that read data from a text file and then search it for a name and return the email address.  It's a huge exercise in using pointers and structures.

The program reads in a text file of names and email addresses then dynamically creates a structure array using `malloc()`.  The `struct Card` is built of two char pointers and I find the length of the data using `strlen()`, `malloc()` memory for that size and assign the struct to the memory address given.

It all seems to work fine until the end after it has printed the name and email and is about to free() the memory.  I get an Aborted (core dump) message every time.  Don't know what the issue could be.

I've placed a `printf()` just before the `free()` to try and track down where the issue is but it appears to be happening either during the name/email printout or just after it happens because my `printf()` test point that is one line before the `free()` is never executed.

I'm assuming the driver program is okay and it has something to do with my functions.
Anyone care to take a stab at it?

```
    //Main
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "lab9utils.h"

    int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

        // Variable declarations.
        struct Card * cards;
        int size;
        int k;
        char * email;

        // Make sure we have 2 extra command-line paramgers.
        if (argc < 3) {
            printf("Usage:  ./lab9.exe <data_filename> <name_to_lookup>");
            return 0;
        }

        // Get the cards and do the lookup.
        cards = getCards(argv[1], &size);
        email = lookup(cards, argv[2], size);

        // Display the output message ("sorry!" or "name -> email").
        if (email == NULL) {
            printf("Sorry, that name was not in the list of cards.\n");
        } else {
            printf("%s -> %s\n", argv[2], email);
        }

        // Free the memory used by the structures.
        k = 0;
        printf("Test Point#1");
        for (k = 0; k < size; k++) {
            free(cards[k].name);
            free(cards[k].email);
        }
        printf("Test Point#2");
        free(cards);

        return 0;
    }





  // Header

    #ifndef LAB9UTILS_H
    #define LAB9UTILS_H

    struct Card {
        char * name;
        char * email;
    };

    struct Card * getCards(char * filename, int * size);
    char * lookup(struct Card * cards, char * name, int size);

    #endif


   //  Functions

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include "lab9utils.h"

    struct Card * getCards(char * filename, int * size_return) {

        int i,size;
        char cTempName[51]={0};
        char cTempEmail[51]={0};

        size = 0;

        //  I/O Setup   
        FILE *fp; 
        fp = fopen(filename,"r");

        //  error checking
        if(fp == NULL)
        {
            perror("Error in opening file");
            return(NULL);
        }

    //  Input Loop      

        while(!feof(fp))
        {
            fscanf(fp,"%s%s",cTempName,cTempEmail);

            size++;
        }   

        size=size-1;

        fclose(fp);

        struct Card * card = (struct Card *)malloc(*size_return * sizeof(struct Card));

        fp = fopen( filename ,"r");

        //  error checking
        if(fp == NULL)
        {
            perror("Error in opening file");
            return(NULL);
        }

        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
            {
                fscanf(fp,"%s%s",cTempName,cTempEmail);
                card[i].name=(char *)malloc((strlen(cTempName)+1));
                card[i].email=(char *)malloc((strlen(cTempEmail)+1));
                strcpy(card[i].name,cTempName);
                strcpy(card[i].email,cTempEmail);

            }

        fclose(fp); 
        //  loop to confirm data was read
        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
                {
                    printf("[ %d ] Name:%s email:%s  Total size:%d\n",i,card[i].name,card[i].email,size);
                }

        *size_return = size;        

        return card;

    }

    char * lookup(struct Card * cards, char * name, int size) {

        int i;

        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
            {
                if (strcmp(cards[i].name,name)==0) 
                {
                    return cards[i].email;
                }
            }

            return NULL;

    }
```

Comment: You know a debugger is *made* for helping you find why your programing is coring, right? And Btw you never set the output variable of `*size_return` before using it for your allocation sizing, so you're `malloc`ing an indeterminate amount of data. ex: this:`malloc(*size_return * sizeof(struct Card))` is wrong.

Comment: Don't have a debugger...instructor has us programming in Notepad++ and using gcc on the cmd line.  Doesn't feel IDEs with all those fancy add-ons like debuggers is good for us.

Comment: **gdb** is anything-but a fancy-add-on debugger, and should be available if you have `gcc`. If it isn't available, tell the instructor someday you'll have to code for a living, and the sooner you know how to use one the better. (you will literally spend half your professional career using one; no joke).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `*size_return` is garbage, because you are setting it to `size` only at the end of the function.

Change this:

```
struct Card * card = (struct Card *)malloc(*size_return * sizeof(struct Card));
```

To this:

```
struct Card * card = (struct Card *)malloc(size * sizeof(struct Card));
```

Comment: Thank you.  I completely missed that.  Made a small change about an hour ago and thought I got all of them.  Work now.